# How to fix the connection about Web api and Node.js is problem

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to ask for permission. I run the android and it is as in the picture. It cannot be connected to the api, but if the service returns to normal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m38c6.jpg)

This problem in Node.js

(node:5932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:5932) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Some phone brands have a security issue that triggers this error. Some things to try:

- Remember to activate "USB Debugging (Security settings)" on your phone's Developer options (caution: not the same as "USB debugging" which should also be active).
- Turn on/off developer mode a couple of times.

You can also try a different phone brand (i.e. Samsung, LG, etc.) to confirm if this is caused by the specific phone you are using for development.

Comment: Try to do it, but it is the same. Once the developer mode is turned on, it is successful, but can not connect to the same web api.

Comment: What error are you getting now? can you edit your post with a screenshot?